# Cocos2d, need to save nsuserdefault object id to game center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I have an object id "score" I need to save to my leader board.

I follow an example and got to this part

```
-(void) onPlayerInfoReceived:(NSArray*)players
{
    CCLOG(@"onPlayerInfoReceived: %@", [players description]);
    GameKitHelper* gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
    [gkHelper submitScore:1234 category:@"scoreboard"];

    [gkHelper showLeaderboard];
}
```

Except I need to save this instead.

```
  _score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];
```

And there is no gamer kit helper reference needed because it is in the same file.

Comment: I think you need to take some time to learn the basics of Objective-C and general programming before you start trying to write a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the question here, but I'll give it a shot. Before I do though, you should definitely do what @Nick Bull said and learn the basics of programming and objective-c.

Now, what I think you want, is to report the score saved in NSUserDefaults to GameCenter instead of "1234".

Replace this line:

```
[gkHelper submitScore:1234 category:@"scoreboard"];
```

With this:

```
[gkHelper submitScore:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"] category:@"scoreboard"];
```

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"]` returns an int right? Therefore, you should be able to pass it in as an argument into your submit score method.

Comment: you see i did this at first, and thought it was wrong simply because game center didn't update, but I now know it takes game center forever to update and it is annoying. Also, you have to have at least 2 accounts up before doing this. Kind of annoying but thanks anyway here is a check mark  for you.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. And yes, it is very annoying how slow Game Center can be and how inconvenient testing sometimes is.